# How to cancel a mandatory (required) field in Virtuemart form submission process?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, virtuemart

I want to free my future site's visitors from having to fill out the form before submitting their name, e-mail and a phone No. Basically, in most cases it won't be needed for them to also add more information in the form's text box. But the default (current) status is that they must at least type a single word before they're allowed to submit the form. I'll attach screenshot to better clarify the issue and also provide a link to a live site where you can see it in a real life situation.

https://www.profilecreations.co.za/index.php/products/desktop-stationery/blockpads/pvc-blockpad-detail

It's a Joomla's Virtuemart shop. Latest Joomla version and VM3 working together. In a product detail page there's an "Ask A Question" button. After it's clicked, you get a contact form, in which one can input their contact info and fill out the text box below and press "Send your question" button just below. My goal is just to directly contact the potential client by using their e-mail or a phone number. I don't need them to necessarily provide me with more information in that text box rectangle.  What I know so far is that there's a Virtuemart controller PHP file that makes sure that the required text box is filled out before the form's submission. This one: components/com_virtuemart/controllers/productdetails.php I'll provide a link to it in a cloud, since I can't post it here.
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4R5G/576VCjoW1

It must be modified so that there wouldn't be a requirement of filling out that text box befere one can submit the form. Here's the link to the real live site's product detail page with an "Ask A Question" button in the middle.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out myself how to solve the issue. First of all, I got rid of the text box and a character counter altogether in file:components/com_virtuemart/views/askquestion/tmpl/form.php
Then I solved the character validation issue in file: components/com_virtuemart/controllers/productdetails.php like so:

```
$min = VmConfig::get ('asks_minimum_comment_length', 0) - 1;
```

In the end, I just get the form with NAME, E-MAIL, PHONE NO. and a captcha validation.

Comment: And rather than editing that file you could have used a template override for it that would save you from having to re-edit after an upgrade. And the second issue looks like a config parameter, but I don't use Virtuemart so I can't confirm that. TMTOWTDI